# Swift - adding cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and I am trying to add some content (`Whish`) in my case. I have set up everything programmatically but somehow adding `cells` is not working for me.

This is my `UITableView` and custom `Wish` Class for my data:

```
    import UIKit

class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    public var wishList : [Wish]?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(WhishCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID)
        self.wishList?.append(Wish(withWishName: "Test"))

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wishList?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath)
        let currentWish = self.wishList![indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentWish.wishName
        return cell
    }

}

class Wish: NSObject {
    public var wishName : String?
    init(withWishName name: String) {
        super.init()
        wishName = name
    }
}
```

And this is how I am creating the `WishlistTableView` inside my other `UIViewController`:

```
let theTableView: WhishlistTableViewController = {
   let v = WhishlistTableViewController()
    v.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    v.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    v.view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    v.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

and its `constraints`:

```
theTableView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.topAnchor, constant: 180.0),
theTableView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
theTableView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
theTableView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0),
```

The `TableView` appears just fine with its `constraints` but adding `cells` is not working and I have no idea why.. Grateful for every help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
public var wishList : [Wish]?
```

with

```
public var wishList = [Wish]()
```

As you never init `wishList` so adding item here `wishList?.append` won't do anything

```
self.wishList.append(Wish(withWishName: "Test"))
```

Also remove this as it's the default

```
// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: that was it ! Thanks you so much :)